# How to install corman lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Does anyone know how to install cormanlisp? I downloaded the open source project from github https://github.com/sharplispers/cormanlisp, but there is no .exe installation package.

[image: Screenshot of extracted source]

Comment: Corman Lisp is nothing to to with [Clojure](https://clojure.org/): it's a Common Lisp, which is very different.  Nevertheless, if you want to install it the [releases](https://github.com/sharplispers/cormanlisp/releases) have MSI installers which I believe are what Windows expects.  I'm leaving this as a comment rather than an answer as I have no idea if they work as I don't have Windows to test them on.

Comment: The src_vc15.sln is a VisualStudio solution file. Please install VisualStudio 2015 and open that file, then compile. It will generate an executable for your system.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have downloaded the source codes. The link you want is https://github.com/sharplispers/cormanlisp/releases which leads to the releases page on GitHub. There is an msi package.